# ¿Qué caracter debo usar en MySQL para reemplazar los saltos de línea representados por la P invertida?

Tags: mysql, caracteres

En una columna de mi tabla se me han colado unos cuantos saltos de línea representados por el símbolo de la P al revés.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo podría hacer un reemplazo seguro de ese carácter por un espacio en blanco?  No sé que carácter tendría que poner como criterio de búsqueda.

Comment: No lo he podido comprobar, pero `replace('tema','\n',' ')` debería de funcionar, sino haz la prueba con un select y luego ya haces el update set

Comment: @rencinas así no me trae ninguna fila: `SELECT * FROM liturgia_misa_lecturas WHERE tema like '%\n%';` y así, me trae demasiada filas: `SELECT * FROM liturgia_misa_lecturas WHERE tema like '%\\n%';`, yo hice una búsqueda desde el IDE copiando/pegando lo que sería el símbolo P invertido y no me trae tantas filas.

Comment: La otra opción habitual sería `\r` (retorno de carro)

Comment: Si la primera consulta no te ha devuelto ningún resultado puede que los saltos de carro sean tipo window$, prueba con: `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn REGEXP '\r\n';` .

Comment: @SJuan76 era precisamente como dices. Usando el `LIKE` con `%\r%` me traía exactamente los registros con salto de línea,he aplicado esta consulta y me ha cambiado los saltos por un espacio en blanco: `UPDATE liturgia_misa_lecturas SET tema = REPLACE(tema, '\r', ' ');` Si quieres lo puedes poner como respuesta para dar el tema por solucionado. Gracias también a los otros por su interés. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso no me ha valido solo con \r pero si me ha funcionado, para esta misma situación en el campo description de una tabla, sustituir por replace(i.description,'\r\n',' ') as description
es decir, con los dos. Creo que el motivo es porque estoy en Windows